# Business Intelligence Reporting

Tags: sql, reporting, birt

All reports of the company have been designed by using BIRT. However , we decided to convert all reports into the Microsoft Reporting Tools. In addition, we use SQL Server 2008 R2 as database. Concerning this , do I have to do these reports by using **Business Intelligence tool in Visual Studio** or do I have to do it in the **SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services** ?

Moreover, How can I install SSRS to SQL Server and how can I install Business Tool into the visual studio?

Answer (score 2):

Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS) comes with SQL Server. You can install it from the SQL Server install (DVD, MSI, ISO). It's a standalone product unless you install Visual Studio in which case you use VS to access BIDS functionality instead, but this will be transparent to you, i.e. VS will open automatically when you try to open BIDS. If you already have VS, then installing BIDS will install as an add in to VS.

Alternatively you can install the Report Builder separately. I quite like this personally, you can get it here...

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=6116

I'm not sure what you mean by SSDR, can you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake. I mean SSRS :) (SQL SERVER REPORTING SERVICES)

Comment: SSRS is installed when you install SQL Server, if you don't have it you will have to run the installation and add in SSRS.

Comment: [FOLLOW, USE AND SHARE the initiative for dedicated BI site.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70503/business-intelligence?referrer=EPHSm8-3avvaMxLjdRIeNg2). I first raised this question in [Meta when there was no BI site proposals.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232414/201662)